# How to hide/show elements based on array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to filter rows in a table based on tags selected by the user.

I used the array of tags to target the class of the rows, I tried to hide the siblings but it doesn't work, it hides everything if there's more than one row, and if the user removes one tag, I need to re-show the other rows, and I didn't manage to find how to do that.

```js
(function($, root, undefined) {

  $(function() {

    'use strict';

    // Disponibilités

    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();

    $('.dropdown').on('click', function(e) {
      var filters = $("input[name='filters']").val();
      var arrayFilters = filters.split(',');
      if (filters) {
        $.each(arrayFilters, function(index, value) {
          $('.' + value).siblings().hide();
        });
      } else {
        $('.uniteRow').show();
      }
    });

  });

})(jQuery, this);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table td {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  </style
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.js"></script>


  <div class="filters">
    <div class="ui multiple dropdown">
      <input type="hidden" name="filters">
      <i class="filter icon"></i>
      <span class="text">Filter les résultats</span>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="header">
          Disponibilité
        </div>
        <div class="scrolling menu">
          <div class="item" data-value="disponiblebientot">
            Disponible bientôt
          </div>
          <div class="item" data-value="juillet2020">
            Juillet 2020
          </div>
          <div class="item" data-value="loue">
            Loué
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="header">
          Pièces
        </div>
        <div class="scrolling menu">
          <div class="item" data-value="pieces3">
            3 ½
          </div>
          <div class="item" data-value="pieces4">
            4 ½
          </div>
          <div class="item" data-value="pieces5">
            5 ½
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <table class="disponibilites">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Pièces</td>
        <td>Disponibilité</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="uniteRow loue pieces4">
        <td>101</td>
        <td>4½</td>
        <td>Loué</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="uniteRow disponiblebientot pieces4">
        <td>102</td>
        <td>4½</td>
        <td>Disponible bientôt</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="uniteRow loue pieces4">
        <td>103</td>
        <td>4½</td>
        <td>Loué</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="uniteRow loue pieces3">
        <td>104</td>
        <td>3½</td>
        <td>Loué</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="uniteRow loue pieces3">
        <td>105</td>
        <td>3½</td>
        <td>Loué</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="uniteRow juillet2020 pieces3">
        <td>106</td>
        <td>3½</td>
        <td>Juillet 2020</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="uniteRow juillet2020 pieces4">
        <td>718</td>
        <td>4½</td>
        <td>Juillet 2020</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

So I want to show only rows that the class is in the arrayFilters, and hide those that are not there, and I want it to update each time a tag is selected/deselected.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML as part of your [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Edited the question to add JSBin, sorry for that, I'm new here

Comment: Code should be placed in a stack snippet in the question itself rather than a third party site.

Comment: @justDan Didn't know how to do that, I'll do it for future questions, thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I modified my code to loop through the rows instead of the array and I changed the data values to classes to use `.is()`.

I check if each row has a class inside the filters and show it, and hide the row if no classes match the filter.

```js
(function ($, root, undefined) {

 $(function () {
  
  'use strict';
  
  // Disponibilités
  
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
  
  $('.dropdown').on('click', function(e) {
   var filters = $( "input[name='filters']" ).val();
   if(filters) {
                $('.uniteRow').each(function (index, value) {
                    if($(this).is(filters)) {
                      $(this).show();
                    } else {
                      $(this).hide();
                    }
                });
   } else {
    $('.uniteRow').show();
   }
  });
  
 });
 
})(jQuery, this);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table td {
    padding: 5px;
  }
  </style
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.js"></script>


 <div class="filters">
 <div class="ui multiple dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="filters">
  <i class="filter icon"></i>
  <span class="text">Filter les résultats</span>
  <div class="menu">
   <div class="divider"></div>
   <div class="header">
    Disponibilité
   </div>
   <div class="scrolling menu">
    <div class="item" data-value=".disponiblebientot">
     Disponible bientôt
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-value=".juillet2020">
     Juillet 2020
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-value=".loue">
     Loué
    </div>
   </div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
   <div class="header">
    Pièces
   </div>
   <div class="scrolling menu">
    <div class="item" data-value=".pieces3">
     3 ½
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-value=".pieces4">
     4 ½
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-value=".pieces5">
     5 ½
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
  
<table class="disponibilites">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>Pièces</td>
   <td>Disponibilité</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="uniteRow loue pieces4">
   <td>101</td>
   <td>4½</td>
   <td>Loué</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="uniteRow disponiblebientot pieces4">
   <td>102</td>
   <td>4½</td>
   <td>Disponible bientôt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="uniteRow loue pieces4">
   <td>103</td>
   <td>4½</td>
   <td>Loué</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="uniteRow loue pieces3">
   <td>104</td>
   <td>3½</td>
   <td>Loué</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="uniteRow loue pieces3">
   <td>105</td>
   <td>3½</td>
   <td>Loué</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="uniteRow juillet2020 pieces3">
   <td>106</td>
   <td>3½</td>
   <td>Juillet 2020</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="uniteRow juillet2020 pieces4">
   <td>718</td>
   <td>4½</td>
   <td>Juillet 2020</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Good job. Thank you for post the solution :)